# ICEfaces dataPaginator actionListener

Tags: jsf, icefaces

In the `ice:dataPaginator` we can add an `actionListener`. Using that event handler or in some other way, can we track the pagination button (anchor) we clicked ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `actionListener` method takes an `ActionEvent` argument on which you can call `getComponent()` and cast it to DataPaginator. With this object, you can use the `getPageIndex()`, `getPageCount()` and `getPaginatorMaxPages()` methods.

It is all written in the ice documentation: http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=compatMenu&exp=paginator

**EDIT:**

```
public void actionListener(ActionEvent event) {
    setStatus("Data Paginator clicked.");

    if ((event.getComponent() != null) &&
        (event.getComponent() instanceof DataPaginator)) {
        DataPaginator clicked = (DataPaginator)event.getComponent();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(80);
        sb.append("Data Paginator clicked. Current page is ");
        sb.append(clicked.getPageIndex());
        sb.append(" of ");
        sb.append(clicked.getPageCount());
        sb.append(" and a maximum of ");
        sb.append(clicked.getPaginatorMaxPages());
        sb.append(" pages will be displayed.");
        setStatus(sb.toString());
    }
}
```